# Excel Object generates error after the application is published

Tags: vb.net, excel

My VB.NET Windows forms application is writing data into excel file. It works without any error in development environment. The excel file gets created with data.

But when the application is deployed/Published. It gives error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at xlWorkBook.SaveAs

Error is confusing. Is it a permission issue? Any help.

Below is the code:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

 Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)

 xlWorkSheet.Name = "Sample1"
 xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "TestData1"
 xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "TestData2"

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(gExcelFileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, _
                                   Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges)
```

Comment: set a breakpoint at the xlWorkBook.SaveAs line and inspect whether xlWorkBook is set to an object reference

Comment: FYI, I don't see gExcelFileName being set or declared?

Comment: Try without the brackets `xlWorkBook.SaveAs gExcelFileName, ...`? When you put brackets `()`, VB expects it to be assigned to a variable.

Comment: VB adds the brackets automatically

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found for this issue is to change the folder location in the variable "gExcelFileName" to a local folder on the machine where it is installed. It works now.  I think it is a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish your application with excel interop dll? different version of excel may have different parameter, if you don't want to publish your application with excel dll, try to use named parameter:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(FileName:=gExcelFileName, 
                  FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, 
                  AccessMode:=Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
                  ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this code. Same error is generated.